# Combine TakeWhile and SkipWhile to partition collection

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to partition `collection` on item, which matches specific condition. I can do that using `TakeWhile` and `SkipWhile`, which is pretty easy to understand:

```
public static bool IsNotSeparator(int value) => value != 3;

var collection = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var part1 = collection.TakeWhile(IsNotSeparator);
var part2 = collection.SkipWhile(IsNotSeparator);
```

But this would iterate from start of `collection` twice and if `IsNotSeparator` takes long it might be performance issue.

Faster way would be to use something like:

```
var part1 = new List<int>();
var index = 0;
for (var max = collection.Length; index < max; ++index) {
    if (IsNotSeparator(collection[i]))
        part1.Add(collection[i]);
    else
        break;
}
var part2 = collection.Skip(index);
```

But that's really less more readable than first example.

So my question is: **what would be the best solution to partition `collection` on specific element?**

What I though of combining those two above is:

```
var collection = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var part1 = collection.TakeWhile(IsNotSeparator).ToList();
var part2 = collection.Skip(part1.Count);
```

Comment: This is a rather opinionated question. What constitutes a "best solution"? Readability? Size of code? Speed? Memory usage?

Comment: @Groo I would go for readability. But if `IsNotSeparator` takes long it might be performance issue.

Comment: Is the list sorted? That would make the biggest performance difference. Also, if you generalize it to work like `String.Split`, then you could make an extension method which might be something like `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split(this IEnumerable<T> list, Predicate<T> match)`, which would return as many chunks there are, separated with the specified item.

Comment: @Groo That's just an example. In my case those are actually `string`s and not `int`s. `IsNotSeparator` is a bit more complicated as well. But I'm interested in generic solution that could be reusable for any type.

Comment: Maybe roll your own extension method that contains the optimized logic you're looking for.  The extension method could have two `out` parameters that are used to store the two arrays after you've divided them.  e.g. `collection.Split(IsSeparator, out part1, out part2);`

Comment: I would not call this a split. It does not omit the delimiter. The delimiter is included as part of the second collection.

Comment: @Chee's Burgers Yes, split might not be the best name. Partitioning would be better.

Comment: @wablab That might be solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick example of how you would do the more general method (multiple splits, as mentioned in the comments), without LINQ (it's possible to convert it to LINQ, but I am not sure if it will be any more readable, and I am in a slight hurry right now):

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this IList<T> list, Predicate<T> match)
{
    if (list.Count == 0)
        yield break;

    var chunkStart = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (match(list[i]))
        {
            yield return new ListSegment<T>(list, chunkStart, i - 1);
            chunkStart = i;
        }
    }

    yield return new ListSegment<T>(list, chunkStart, list.Count - 1);
}
```

The code presumes a class named `ListSegment<T> : IEnumerable<T>` which simply iterates from `from` to `to` over the original list (no copying, similar to how `ArraySegment<T>` works (but is unfortunately limited to arrays).

So the code will return as many chunks as there are matches, i.e. this code:

```
var collection = new[] { "A", "B", "-", "C", "D", "-", "E" };
foreach (var chunk in collection.Split(i => i == "-"))
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", chunk));
```

would print:

```
A, B
-, C, D
-, E
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the Array Copy methods:

```
var separator = 3;
var collection = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

var i = Array.IndexOf(collection,separator);

int[] part1 = new int[i];
int[] part2 = new int[collection.Length - i];
Array.Copy(collection, 0, part1, 0, i ); 
Array.Copy(collection, i, part2, 0, collection.Length - i );
```

Alternatively to be more efficient use ArraySegment:

```
var i = Array.IndexOf(collection,separator);
var part1 = new ArraySegment<int>( collection, 0, i );
var part2 = new ArraySegment<int>( collection, i, collection.Length - i );
```

ArraySegment is a wrapper around an array that delimits a range of elements in that array. Multiple ArraySegment instances can refer to the same original array and can overlap.

> Edit - add combination of original question with ArraySegment so as not to iterate collection twice.

```
public static bool IsNotSeparator(int value) => value != 3;
var collection = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

var index = collection.TakeWhile(IsNotSeparator).Count();

var part1 = new ArraySegment<int>( collection, 0, index );
var part2 = new ArraySegment<int>( collection, index, collection.Length - index );
```

Comment: It would be easy if I would know separator index in advance. I don't know which index I need to split on in advance and it is determined by `IsNotSeparator` method.

Comment: @DovydasSopa surely you can rewrite your IsNotSeparator as GetSeparator method which returns the separator and then you can use the Array.IndexOf method as per my answer